# Simple Geometry Simple Solution

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Let $ABCD$ be a square with sides length $2$. Let $\omega$ be a circle with the center $A$ and radius $2$ and $\gamma$ a semicircle with the diameter BC (see the picture below). Find the area bounded by $\omega$,$\gamma$ and the line $CD$.

[image]

The problem can be solved by noticing that $ABOK$ is a cyclic quadrilateral and applying Ptolemy's theorem there. However, it requires a lot of calculation (calculating BK than the area of the BK segment and etc.) I wonder if there is more elegant solution. If so please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $\angle OAK = \theta$, then $\angle KAD = \dfrac{\pi}{2} - 2 \theta$ and $\angle COK = 2 \theta$

Area of sector $COK = \theta$

Area of sector $KAD  \displaystyle  = \left(\frac{\pi}{4} - \theta\right) \cdot 4 = \pi - 4 \theta$

Area of ABOK $ = 2 \cdot S_{\triangle AOK} = 2$

Area of square $ABCD = 4$

Desired area $ = 4 - (2 + \pi  - 3 \theta) = 2 + 3 \theta - \pi$

Note that $~ \tan \theta = \frac12 \implies \theta = \arctan(1/2) \approx 0.46365$